# I want to make a button click last 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, html, css

To elaborate. I have an animation code in CSS that I want to remain active for 3 seconds after each button click. My code
HTML

Need a solution. Thanks

```js
function coinflip() {
  // gets random value from 0-1
  var coinside = Math.random();
  //get ready to change the img src
  var img = document.getElementById("coinimage");
  // if coin is greater than or equal to 0.5 then good
  if (coinside <= 0.5) {
    img.src = "CatCoingood.png";
  } else {
    // when less then 0.5 
    img.src = "CatCoinbad.png";
  }
}
```

```css
.catcoinZ {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.catcoinZ:active {
  perspective: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 25vh;
  transform: rotateY(45deg);
  animation: rotateAnimation 1s linear infinite;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes rotateAnimation {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(45deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(225deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="catcoinZ" onclick="coinflip();"><img id="coinimage" src="CatCoindefault.png" width="250" height="250"></button>
```

Comment: What do you mean by remain active? You cannot interrupt it?

Comment: you mean like the time adds up each time you click the button?? like first click 3s and second click 6s and so on??

Answer (score 0):

Is this the functionality your are looking for? Change from `:active` to `.active` and then add and remove the class using Jquery.

```js
function coinflip() {
  // gets random value from 0-1
  var coinside = Math.random();
  //get ready to change the img src
  var img = document.getElementById("coinimage");
  // if coin is greater than or equal to 0.5 then good
  if (coinside <= 0.5) {
    img.src = "CatCoingood.png";
  } else {
    // when less then 0.5 
    img.src = "CatCoinbad.png";
  }
}

$("button").click(function() {
  var button = $(this);
  $(button).addClass('active');
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    $(button).removeClass('active');
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
.catcoinZ {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.catcoinZ.active {
  perspective: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 25vh;
  transform: rotateY(45deg);
  animation: rotateAnimation 1s linear infinite;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes rotateAnimation {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(45deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(225deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="catcoinZ" onclick="coinflip();"><img id="coinimage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="250" height="250"></button>
```